# Can you create a mobile version of your website from scratch, if so how?

Tags: html, css, mobile, web

I'v created my website and I have been trying to research how to create a mobile version for it. However I thought it would be the same as scripting in notepad or sublime etc. Can you create one from scratch using notepad or sublime? Or should I just use the tools provided on the web such as 'Mobify'. (I'd prefer to learn from scratch)

Thanks in advance,

Noob developer.

Comment: You're going to want to research CSS `media-queries` - http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/ I take it you want to make the site `responsive`? - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Comment: *Can you create a mobile version of your website from scratch?* - Yes you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have created your existing website from sctrach, there should be no problem changing it to mobile. Just add an altered css file, which contains the css for your mobile version. and add a javascript function to your page, which loads the css file depending on the device the page is requested from.

If you have built your site using tools, it is the easiest to do the transformation using tools.

Comment: Thank you, question answered. I will create it from scratch, how would you test it though before putting it live?

Comment: Host your website on localhost (computer should be in a network, that has wifi), connect your mobile with the wifi network and access the page